# How to test Observables throwing errors (with throwError) if the implementation subscribe's to it already?

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, jasmine

Let's suppose I have an Angular component with this HTML (extract):

```
<some-thirdparty-component
    (onClickCallback)="handleChange($event)"
```

I have a function to handle this. It forwards it to `service.saveSomething` (which returns an Observable). Simple enough. As a wrapped component, I need to `subscribe`, as I obviously want to get it executed.

```js
  public handleChange(event: any) {
     this.service.saveSomething(event)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)) // additional error handling may be piped here
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Let's suppose I want to test this. Especially, I want to test the **error case** i.e. when it (aka saving or whatever) fails:

```js
    let dataMock = {};

    it('should throw error', waitForAsync(() => {
      const error = new Error('test error');
      spyOn(service, 'saveSomething').and.returnValue(throwError(error));

      expect(() => {
        component.handleChange(dataMock);
      }).toThrow();

      expect(service.saveSomething).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(dataMock);
      expect(toastService.showToast).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(/** **/); // an additional error handling in the pipe to test in a different implementation
    }));
```

The issue is the test fails, in this version with "Expected function to throw an exception.".

When I change it to not expect an error to be thrown though:

```
      component.handleChange(dataMock);
```

Then jasmine actually throws an error however, which makes the test fail:

> Error: test error in main.js

I already wrapped [it in `waitForAsync`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-testing-async-fakeasync), which is usually useful in such cases.

My guess is, the issue is that throwing the exception happens in an asynchronous way due to how Observables work. The Observable error is converted into a JS `Error` and being thrown. However, I cannot catch this via jasmine `toThrow`, because it happens at the end, i.e. via `waitForAsync` and is only catched there. But it is too late to assert anything.

Also I cannot expose the Observable (which would be the usual way), as someone needs to subscribe in productive code. Just exposing it for testing reasons, also does not seem clean to me.

Kind of an chicken/egg problem...

So what to do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question regarding the observables issue, personally I would do something like this regarding calling observables and subscribing to them in your codebase with error throwing / handling logic as well.

```
  public handleChange(event: any) {
     this.assignmentService.saveSomething(event)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe({
        next: (value: any) => {
    console.log(value, 'success!!!');
    },
    error: (err: any) => {
      console.error('error detected, printing out the output error msg:', err);
    }
      });

  }
```

hopefully I understood your question right, this code above is a good way of handling errors outputed from observables and subscriptions. If you're question was related to how to handle jasmin errors, I personally have not used jasmin, but you can try implementing it with this code in mind maybe.

Hope this helps! Have a good day man! :) :) :)

Comment: Yeah, but is this the only and suggested option? So you would always need to handle the error, and _always_ usually console.log it? I would have thought throwing is fine in case of unexpected errors in Angular components.